# Class instance interactions

Tags: python, class

Variations on python class implementation where instances interact

I've written three versions on my menu system class. They where:

```
class Menu(object)
```

The menu instances are stored in `__dict__`. I refer to menu data with `self.data`.

```
class Menu(dict)
```

The menu instances are stored in the dict subclassed by my class. I refer to menu data with `self[data]`.

```
class Menu(object)
```

The menu data is stored in a `cls.data` dict that I establish in `__init__()`. The class is mostly a method container and I don't benefit from the instance member features.

Each has their positive and negative aspects but they all smell bad. I think what I have learned is that if you develop a class where one instance has to be able to interact with another instance, the schema falls apart since one method may need to transition between instances.

For example, if I have a front panel LCD with a Main Menu screen and four hotkeys to select other menus, some methods will need to be able to navigate across instance boundaries and this is totally kicking my butt. When something is this unpleasant, it usually means that there is something important to learn. So, can any of you help me out? How can you best write code where instances interact within a method?

```
           Main Menu

  Port    Network    Device
 Setup     Setup      Setup     Next>
```

When I push the button under Port Setup, the `Menu` class needs to switch its instance from the Main Menu instance to the Port Setup instance using a method that belongs to the class/instance. But how?

```
         Port Setup Menu

  Baud      Stop    Parity    Protocol
  Rate      Bits     Bit      Address
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your post is riddled with inaccuracies so it is hard to understand what you are even asking. 1) "The menu instances are stored in `__dict__` " no, they are not. The instances *aren't stored anywhere*. the `__dict__` attribute refers to the *namespace of your instances*. 2) "The menu instances are stored in the dict subclassed by my class" No, they are not. the instances *aren't stored anywhere*. Your instances *are `dict` objects*.

Comment: Fundamentally, you need to give *specific example* of what you are talking about. Everything in python is an instance, so every method involves interactions between instances. give an example of what you mean by: "a class where one instance has to be able to interact with another instance, the schema falls apart since one method may need to transition between instances." And also, " some methods will need to be able to navigate across instance boundaries " because none of it makes sense to me, you clearly mean something specific, so please provide a specific example.